# Firebase Storage security rules for images in a chat app

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

In my chat app, I would like images sent in a conversation and profile pictures of users stored in Firebase Storage to only be visible to users that belong to that conversation/are together in a conversation.
From what I've read this is only possible with custom claims, but this seems unnecessarily difficult.

Let's say that a user wants to access an image of a conversation, he has to send a claim that he belongs to the conversation.
He either has to constantly send a list of conversations he belongs to, and this happens with every request, or claims need to be constantly given or taken away by a Cloud Function that checks if a user belongs to a conversation and then the client has to choose which ones get sent with the auth object.

Besides, a user would have to sign out and sign in to receive the new claim.

Is there a way to make this process simpler, or to solve this problem in an other, easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to store the download URL in the chat's database.
Use https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url to generate the URL after the image is uploaded

Comment: That's useful, but it doesn't really solve the problem of the possibility of accessing images outside of a conversation. Or do you mean that it is practically impossible to guess the URL/location of an image as an outsider without being on the receiving end of the image, in the conversation?

Comment: @DaddyMike That is exactly the point. The url will contain a token, which is practically impossible to guess. Although the file would be public, no one will ever access it unless they have the token.

Comment: But couldn't an attacker just guess the location of the photo and use the getDownloadURL method on it? So should I also implement some form of key, for example the one generated by .push to save the photo to a location known only to the uploader?

Comment: Using an extra key in the filename/pathname could be more secure but is not really necessary. You have to restrict access to your files with the firebase rules. Only the file owner should have access and therefore only he is able to call getDownloadURL. The owner can then share the url (which also contains the file's location) e.g. save the url in your database.

Comment: @KevinKreps that's exactly how my current implementation looks like. In my case, I am using getSignedURL (admin mode), which expires in the year 2100. I was also afraid of the scenario where someone guesses the URL, but yes, it seems impossible with the token, and I think that denying the `read` action with Firebase Storage Rules for the entire bucket, and adding an extra security layer like the AppCheck service is OK.